# different type Objects as parameter of a function

Tags: iphone

I created 2 objects subclass from NSObject

AObject, BObject

Is it possible to transfer variables of these 2 objects to a same function?

such as

```
-(void)myFunction:(AObject *)obj;

-(void)myFunction:(BObject *)obj;
```

I tested in xcode, it is not allowed.
Is there any replacement method?

Welcome any comment

Thanks
interdev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options. Here are four that come to mind, each with their own pros and cons:

1. Discriminate by signature:

   ```
   - (void)myFunctionWithA:(AObject *)obj;
   - (void)myFunctionWithB:(BObject *)obj;
   ```
2. Declare a parameter of type `NSObject *` (or `id`, as suggested in the comments) and query the type inside the function.
3. As above, but constrain it by declaring a common base class `BaseObject *`, from which `AObject` and `BObject` inherit.
4. Combine the base class with a trampoline technique:

   ```
   - (void)myFunction:(BaseObject *)base {
       [base myTrampoline:self];
   }
   ```

   `BaseObject` declares the abstract method `myTrampoline:`, which `AObject` and `BObject` implement.

Without knowing more about your problem, it's impossible to say which is best.

Comment: @gcamp I'd second that. Especially since not all Objective-C objects are `NSObject*` (some are `NSProxy*` as well, though this is relatively rare). Whereas `id` is a synonym for `struct objc_object *`, which works for any object. Doesn't matter a whole lot, though.

Answer (score 1):

It's been suggested to just type your parameter as `id`, but if you are feeling awesome, you can enforce compile-time checking that your object will actually be able to do what you need: use a protocol.

```
@protocol DoingSomething <NSObject>
// whatever methods you intend to call on the parameter of that one method
@end

//...
- (void)myFunction:(id<DoingSomething>)param {
    // only send messages to param that are in <DoingSomething> and <NSObject>
}
//...
```